# Open clipboard data using some hotkey

Tags: windows, clipboard, copy-paste

Is there some tool that enables to use some hotkey that will open the file system/URL with the path saved in my clipboard?

I mean if I have *c:\victor\longpath\something\something* in my clipboard, I want to be able to use some hotkey to open it in a default application. Currently I have to paste it to the *Start* → *Run* field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Clipmon](http://www.clipboardmonitor.de/index_en.htm) clipboardmonitor is

> a tiny application which monitors the clipboard and executes programs depending on the clipboard's content.
>
> For text content it's able to open:
>
> - The default browser for HTTP or HTTPS addresses
> - The email client for email addresses
> - The explorer for a detected folder or file path